# apply jquery ui to can.Component template

Tags: jquery-ui, canjs

I am creating a menu component using can.Component with JQueryUI and mustaches.

The can.Component renders a mustache template. Naturally, this loads the partial into the DOM.

My problem is this:

Apply the jQuery UI functionality to the menu, I have to invoke:

```
$('#menu').menu();
```

... after the partial is injected into the DOM. How may I do this within the component? I tried placing the prior line within the init function in the events. However, that did not work. Is there some after hook where I may place this code? That way after the component loads the template I can then apply the jquery stuff from within the component itself.

This is what I have so far, that does not work:

```
var Menu = can.Component.extend({
  tag: 'menu',
  template: can.view('/assets/neo_admin/views/menu.mustache'),
  events: {
    init: function(){
        $('#menu').menu();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: We discussed some strategies in another thread recently.  See if this helps you out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974803/how-to-bind-an-event-to-can-control-to-run-whenever-an-element-matching-the-sele  -- I recommend using a Mustache helper to you, just as I did to the person who posed that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `inserted` event and look up on `this.element`:

```
var Menu = can.Component.extend({
  tag: 'menu',
  template: can.view('/assets/neo_admin/views/menu.mustache'),
  events: {
    inserted: function(){
        this.element.find('#menu').menu();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Daff, thanks for your answer! Where can I find all of events emitted by `can.Component` ? Couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it's a little hidden. You can find the docs at http://canjs.com/docs/can.events.html